# use of undeclared type NSLinguisticTagScheme

Tags: swift4, macos-high-sierra, nslinguistictagger

I have the code working in a playground, and Xcode shows no bugs, but when I compile the file on the command line it comes back with the errors

```
use of undeclared type NSLinguisticTagScheme
and String has no member 'tokenType'
```

Heres the problem code.

```
let tagSchemes : [NSLinguisticTagScheme] = [ .tokenType]
let tagger : NSLinguisticTagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: tagSchemes, options: 0)
let options : NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [ .omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace]

tagger.string = text
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)

tagger.enumerateTags( in: range, unit: .sentence, scheme: .tokenType, options: options, using: 
{ tag, tokenRange, stop in
    let token = (text as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
    sentences.append(token)
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `NSLinguisticTagScheme` is available starting iOS 11. Have you checked your Deployment Target?

Comment: Yea, currently deploying to macOS 10.13, using swift 4

Comment: Couldn't replicate your problem on macOS 10.13

Comment: were you able to compile the file using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Updating Xcode solved the issue